# Azure DevOps Project Administrator cannot manage Git permissions

Tags: permissions, git, azure

My DevOps team members who are members of Project Administrators group cannot manage the Git repository - the following error message is shown for Project Settings->Repositories: "You don't have the authority to view the permissions for this object."

According to [Set repository permissions for Git or TFVC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/set-git-tfvc-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops) membership in Project Administrators group allows managing the team's repositories.

I am only able to manage these permissions using my login that purchased my VS Pro subscription. It is like this identity is some kind of global administrator because it is not a member of any project group (according to Project Settings->Permissions).

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**

Users with *Stakeholder* access level (it refers to user license) don't have access to Git Repo although these have enought rights at project or organization level. Check access level each user you have at https://dev.azure.com/(your-organization-name-here)/_settings/users

[image]

**More info**

Each organization of Azure *DevOps* come with 5 Basic user licenses. Those licenses have access to Git Repo unlike *Stakeholder*.
To give access to Git Repo to more users you should buy more Basic licenses unles users already have Visual Studio license, in this case you only need to set their access level as *Visual Studio Subscriber*.

Reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/permissions-access?view=azure-devops